# Excel column with duplicate values, return index value another column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Here's my problem. I have a left column with some duplicate values in its rows. Column on right has an "index" on the the first same row where duplicate first appears on left.

How to find the duplicates on left, then return the values on right (empty), repeating the value on same right column corresponding to the left.

Simple sample attached. Need to populate B4-B6 with "B", and B8-B9 with "C".

[image: Sample table]

It's a spreadsheet with about 20,000 lines.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following steps too.

**Step 1**

> Select the range that contains blank cells you need to fill.

[image]

**Step 2**

> Click **Home** > **Find & Select** > **Go To Special…**, and a **Go To Special** dialog box will appear, then check **Blanks** option.

[image]

**Step 3**

> Click **OK**, and all of the blank cells have been selected. Then input the formula "**=B3**" into active cell **B4** without changing the selection.

[image]

**Step 4**

> Press **Ctrl + Enter**, Excel will copy the respective formula to all blank cells.

[image]

**Step 5**

At this point, the filled contents are formulas, and we need to convert the formals to values. Then select the whole range, copy it, and then press **Ctrl + Alt + V** to active the **Paste Special…** dialog box. Then select **Values** option from **Paste**, and select **None** option from **Operation**.

[image]

**Step 6**

> Then click **OK**. And all of the formulas have been converted to values.

Answer (score 1):

Use this simple if condition to resolve your Question
in coloumn C

```
  A     B                C
1 Left Right         Right
2 1    A     =IF(B2="",C1,B2)-----> A
3 2    B     =IF(B2="",C1,B2)-----> B
4 2          =IF(B2="",C1,B2)-----> B
5 2          =IF(B2="",C1,B2)-----> B
6 2          =IF(B2="",C1,B2)-----> B
7 3    C     =IF(B2="",C1,B2)-----> C
8 3          =IF(B2="",C1,B2)-----> C
```

Please do not fix Any Cell.

Please connect if still need clarity

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Here's the formula you are looking for:

```
=IF(A2=A1,"",SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,A2,4),"1",""))
```

Here's my result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I corrected KOBY DOUEK's formula:

=IF(A2=A1,**B1**,SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,A2,4),"1",""))